# Getting PDF page count in C# using static wkHTMLtoPDF

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using the following wrapper [WkHtmlToXSharp](https://github.com/pruiz/WkHtmlToXSharp)  to convert HTML reports into PDF.  I would like to also record the page count after the conversion is complete.

Is there a way to extract the page count from the binary PDF in memory?  Or do I need to use secondary PDF libraries such as iTextSharp to extract the page count from the PDF?

Using the Javascript in the page footer/header is not acceptable solution as this can be a data heavy 60-80 pages report.

Thanks,
Rafi

Answer (score 0):

If you generate the PDF yourself, you could try counting them directly from the PDF source format. There are tutorials available for that in for example in  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14768/Counting-PDF-Pages-using-Regular-Expressions

I won't repeat them here but the idea is to count how many `/Type /Page` hits there are on the PDF using regex. Open a generated PDF in a good text editor and you'll see them yourself. Watch out for one "/Type /Pages" which throws the number off by one, finding a good regex is easy when you "control" the PDF generation or at least know that it's consistent.